# How to set, or get, local system log file in C?

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I was wondering how to set or find the local log files on your computer in Linux. I was reading the GNU C guide on syslog, and when you open a log, you declare the log your going to write to. In the examples they have LOG_LOCAL0, LOG_LOCAL1, LOG_LOCAL2, etc.. How do you set these, or where are they located? I was also wondering where LOG_SYSLOG is located? When i was looking under /var/log, i didn't see anything that looked like a system log. I cannot seem to find much online about the log files themselves. Only how to use the syslog functions.

Comment: `/etc/syslog.conf` tells `syslogd` where it should write to for each type of log message.

Comment: Do you define this file yourself?

Comment: There should be a default one that comes with the distribution, you can customize it if you want.

Comment: Under `/var/log` you should probably see a file `syslog`, that's the main system log file.

Comment: i don't have a default /etc/syslog.conf file. Should i create one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Propably your system has `/etc/rsyslog.conf` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in linux (I'm running ubuntu 14.04)

the log files are (by default) in /var/log/

one of those files is 'syslog'
if the system has been up for a while
there will also be files named similar to:
'syslog.#.gz'  which is a zipped file of the prior syslog(s)